# Constructor annotation on java records

Tags: java, constructor, annotations, java-record, java-16

Is there a way to get an annotation like [ConstructorProperties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html) that has `@Target(CONSTRUCTOR)` to annotate the generated constructor of a java 16 record? E.g.:

```
@ConstructorProperties({"id", "filename"})
public record Person(long id, String filename) {}
```

This ^ causes the following error:

```
java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

Answer (score 15):

This worked:

```
public record Person(long id, String filename) {
    @ConstructorProperties({"id", "filename"})
    public Person {}
}
```

My understanding is that the inner constructor with no parameter list is a way of adding logic to the default constructor created using the component list. Apparently, adding a constructor annotation to that has the end result I was after :)

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended solution.  The syntactic form you describe is called a _compact constructor_; it is a concise way of declaring the _canonical constructor_ of a record, which is the constructor whose argument list matches that of the record.

Comment: It would be even better, if the Java Beans gets an update to recognize records, eliminating the need for the `@ConstructorProperties` annotation…

Comment: @BrianGoetz are you sure? I’ve read http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/ and get a different impression. For an outsider, it’ll take an hour to implement and weeks for trying to get it into the JDK…

Comment: @Holger The first few times will take longer, for sure.  And yes, the non-code aspects can overshadow the code aspects -- and this is true for my job too.  But that's just what "contribute" means at the scale of Java -- the code is only a small part of the work.  (So yes, contributions are welcome, but "here's my code" is not the contribution most people think it is.)